# Get Area Name from Street Address in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am developing a website where I plot statistics for an area and show it on Google Maps.

If you search Google Maps for "Harlem New York, NY USA" or "University Heights Bronx, NY USA", it shades that entire area. I will be showing this area and will figure out a way to show markers with statistics over this.

However, given the user will input addresses such as "500 W 133rd St, New York, NY 10027, USA", is it possible, using some Google Map API or something, to retrieve the Area Name (Harlem), from the mentioned street address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [Google Maps Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#GeocodingResponses)
(in order to use it, you need a [Gecoding API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key))

For your example "500 W 133rd St, New York, NY 10027, USA" you may call the API in the following way:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=500%20W%20133rd%20St,%20New%20York,%20NY%2010027,%20USA

If you provide a proper key you should get a following JSON:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "500",
               "short_name" : "500",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "West 133rd Street",
               "short_name" : "W 133rd St",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Upper Manhattan",
               "short_name" : "Upper Manhattan",
               "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Manhattan",
               "short_name" : "Manhattan",
               "types" : [ "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "New York",
               "short_name" : "New York",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "New York County",
               "short_name" : "New York County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "New York",
               "short_name" : "NY",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Stany Zjednoczone",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "10027",
               "short_name" : "10027",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "7302",
               "short_name" : "7302",
               "types" : [ "postal_code_suffix" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "500 W 133rd St, New York, NY 10027, Stany Zjednoczone",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.8176249,
                  "lng" : -73.9532346
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.8176127,
                  "lng" : -73.9532442
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.8176127,
               "lng" : -73.9532442
            },
            "location_type" : "RANGE_INTERPOLATED",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.81896778029149,
                  "lng" : -73.9518904197085
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.81626981970849,
                  "lng" : -73.95458838029151
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "Eic1MDAgVyAxMzNyZCBTdCwgTmV3IFlvcmssIE5ZIDEwMDI3LCBVU0E",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Which you can filter out for `neighborhood`, `sublocality_level_1` or `postal_code` types and get the related `long_name` to search for the polygon.

Comment: I tried the above earlier, but didn't use it for the following two reasons. 1) It does not return Harlem, which you can visually see is the area on the map. 2) When I tried a couple of other addresses, it returned sublocality_level_2 as the narrower/smaller area, but in cases such as yours, only sublocality_level_1 is mentioned, but does have neighborhood. Any idea what's up with that?

Comment: I suppose that Harlem is just a polygon spatial object, but not a part of the regions structure (if we ask about Harlem we will get Manhattan as the most accurate region):
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Harlem,New%20York,%20NY%2010027,%20USA

Comment: The other idea is that you try Nominatim (a service over OpenStreetMap), in a similar two step approach:
Discover id: http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=500%20W%20133rd%20St,%20New%20York,%20NY%2010027,%20USA&format=json

Use id to get details: http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/details.php?place_id=1672811647

Although you still do not get Harlem in the structure at least with Nominatim you would get ID's of objects from OpenStreetMap, so it should be easier for the next stepsof application

Comment: In reality, I needed the user to discover Harlem, but for now, I am showing Upper Manhattan. The next step would be to let them scroll around and zoom my embedded map, and I'll just draw a basic rectangle shaded area around their current view. I am accepting this, can you see whether you can answer this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36780433/get-geocode-of-embedded-maps